# pass vars from javascript ajax to php

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, variables

I just search around web without found solution :

I have a script where I have this code to reload a query resident in `ftp_logs_table2.php` without manually refresh the script.

```
<div id="show"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function() {
      $('#show').load('ftp_logs_table2.php')
    }, 1000);
  });
</script>
```

the problem is that I have to pass 2 vars to the query on `ftp_logs_table2.php` and I don't know howto :
thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) or [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)?

Comment: ajax or server sent events would be better but perhaps you could do `$('#show').load('ftp_logs_table2.php?param1=value1&param2=value2')` etc and within `ftp_logs_table2.php` use `$_GET['param1']` etc etc

Comment: I thanks for help, I just try to use this method but as this I load the ftp_logs_table2.php with the rights $vars but without the rest of the script that is after this load.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up for jQuery ajax function like this.  To pass parameters to the server, user the `data` attribute:

```
<div id="show"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
                setInterval(function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'ftp_logs_table2.php',
                            data: { var1: 'data', var2: 'data' },
                            method: 'POST',
                            success: function(data) {
                                $('#show').html(data);
                            }
                        })
                }, 1000);
        });
</script>
```

That is a very basic example.  There is great jQuery documentation and examples, as always http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: finally found the solution ! Thanks ( really ) ! I note that I have to $_GET the data values, it is possible to $_POST ?

Comment: Yeah using the `method` parameter, also in the documentation.  Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're already using jQuery, so you can use the `$.ajax` function from that library.

With passing data to your PHP file your code will look something like the following;

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "ftp_logs_table2.php",
  data: { this: "that", foo: "bar" }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
  alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

The docs for it can be found here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/